# Solr highlighting - need to bold the highlighted phrase

Tags: solr

I am doing a solr search and highlighting the results. But by default the highligthed match term is wrapped with  *and* . I need to change it and just want to bold the highlighted match term. Will someone tell me the how to bring the css and what change I need to do in solr-config.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the param hl.simple.pre and hl.simple.post in solrconfig.xml to

```
   <str name="hl.simple.pre">&lt;b&gt;</str>
   <str name="hl.simple.post">&lt;/b&gt;</str>
```

which wraps the highlighted fragment with  **and** . Alternatively, you can also use css to change the appearance of  which is the default Solr settings.

More can be found in this wiki:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.simple.pre.2Fhl.simple.post